# PyTorch Generating Matrix using a Kernel Function without For-Loops

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to generate a matrix (tensor object on PyTorch) that is similar to Gram matrix except I need to apply a kernel function instead of inner product on my input matrix.

For loops like the one below works:

```
N = x.shape[0] # x.shape = (N,d)
G = torch.zeros((N,N)) 
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        G[i][j] = K(x[i], x[j])
```

where x is my input tensor whose shape is (N,d) and the kernel function K(a,b) yields a real value after performing some math. For example:

```
def K(a,b):
   return ((1+(a*b)).sum()).pow(2) #second degree polynomial.
```

I want to generate this matrix, G without having to change the kernel function K() and of course, without for-loops!

My initial attempt is to use a lambda approach but this code below obviously doesn't work as it only yields a list of k(x[i],x[i]).

```
G = torch.tensor(list(map(lambda a,b: K(a,b),x,x))
```

How can I use the lambda function to yield N-by-N matrix?
What would be some other ways to tackle this problem?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `(1+(a*b).sum()).pow(2) ` instead?

Comment: @bobcat Yes. You are right. Just edited the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate `G` from `x` simply with:

```
G = (1 + torch.matmul(x, x.T)).pow(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This is something I would have done if I had control over the function. In the task I am working on, I have to use the function given.

Comment: @JKim This is the answer to your question. It calculates `G` from `x`.

Comment: Yes it does. But the original question was that I have to be calling this kernel function provided for the task, and I can't make changes to the kernel function. I shouldn't be by passing the kernel function and hard code it. There are multiple kernel functions n-degree polynomial functions, RBF, etc. The constraint is to "use kernel function provided and populate kernelized matrix"

Comment: @JKim My code is not "changing" `K`. I'm pretty sure this homework question is referring to *using* the mathematical function of `K`, not *calling* the Python function `K`.

Comment: No. It is calling the Python function K. Like I said before, we are given with utility functions. I figured it out anyway. Thanks for your time!